# Select act as a dropdown, prevent text/selection change with HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

Curious, I'm using HTML select for additional options inside a responsive table. The pretty HTML/CSS dropdowns don't work since they're nested inside a scrollable responsive table, so they get cut-off. The best solution was to just use HTML select, but I don't want the actual menu options (e.g. Rename, Duplicate, Delete) to change the placeholder text (e.g. More), rather I'd like to have them perform those actions without changing the text. Hope that makes sense, basically work as a typical CSS dropdown would work. Thoughts? Ideas?

**Example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/gqh5at0u/

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>More</option> <!-- I want this to stay visible -->
    <option>Rename</option>
    <option>Duplicate</option>
    <option disabled="disabled">----</option>
    <option>Delete</option>
</select>
```

Comment: sounds like a drop down menu? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just reset the value when you catch the event.

```js
$('.form-control').on('change', function(evt) {
    var select = $(this);
    alert(select.val()); // do stuff
    
    select.val('none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="none" disabled selected hidden>More</option> <!-- I want this to stay visible -->
    <option>Rename</option>
    <option>Open in Editor</option>
    <option>Duplicate</option>
    <option>Shift Due Date</option>
    <option>Copy from Section</option>
</select>
```